# Topology defined by bounded continuous functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

Consider the collection S of all bounded continuous functions from real line to itself with usual topology.

Let T denote the topology on real line with subbase given by $f^{-1}((a,b))$, where $f\in S$ and $a$, $b$ are reals. I was trying to prove that T coincides with usual topology on real line. I don't know whether this is correct, but my argument for it is following.

Under continuous function, bounded or not, the inverse image of an open interval is open.

Let $(a, b) $ be ant open interval. Let $f$ be the function defined by $f(x) =x$ for $x\in (a-1, b+1) $, and $f(x) =a-1$ if $x<a-1$, $f(x) =b+1$ if $x>b+1$.

Then pull back of the interval $(a, b) $ is the same open interval, so we do not really get new subbase elements.

Thus T coincides with usual topology on real line.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. Of course, if $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space, if $\mathcal F$ is a set of continuous functions from $X$ into a topological space $(Y,\tau^\star)$, and if $S\subset\tau^\star$, then the topology $\tau'$ generated by$$\left\{f^{-1}(A)\,\middle|\,A\in S\wedge f\in\mathcal{F}\right\}$$is a subset of $\tau$. This is always true. All that remained was to prove that, in your specific situation, $\tau=\tau'$, you that's exactly what you did.